# mongod process restarting frequently - version 3.2.9

Tags: mongodb

mongod process restarting frequently with this:

```
E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (13) [1484274727:920198][12108:0x7f9e77225700], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /data/mongodb/data/WiredTiger.turtle: file-exist: stat: Permission denied
E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (13) [1484274727:920463][12108:0x7f9e77225700], checkpoint-server: checkpoint server error: Permission denied
 E STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger (-31804) [1484274727:920485][12108:0x7f9e77225700], checkpoint-server: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
        [thread2] Fatal Assertion 28558
        [thread2]
        [WTJournalFlusher] Fatal Assertion 28559
        [WTJournalFlusher]
        [thread2] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Permissions of file:

```
 /data/mongodb/data# ll WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 945 Jan 13 05:56 WiredTiger.turtle
```

Current version is 3.2.9. This is upgraded version from 2.X . We are managing mongodb service through chef.

Do I need to start service with `service mongodb` or `service mongod`? I see that service is starting by user `mongodb` and group `nogroup`.

```
/data/mongodb/data# ll /proc/8241
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x   9 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 02:34 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 111 root    root    0 Sep  1 04:38 ../
dr-xr-xr-x   2 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 attr/
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 autogroup
-r--------   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 02:34 auxv
-r--r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 cgroup
--w-------   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 clear_refs
-r--r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 02:37 cmdline
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 comm
-rw-r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 coredump_filter
-r--r--r--   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 cwd -> //
-r--------   1 mongodb nogroup 0 Jan 13 04:07 environ
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo service mongodb start` to start the service. It will start the MongoDB service from the relevant user. It won't occur any errors once you do that.

Comment: I have started the service using service mongod start and modified init file to start with group "mongodb" .. Issue is resolved now.. Thanks for your response.